# How to dynamically add and handle progressbars (linearprogressindicator) in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I had a simple idea: a button that with each click creates a LinearProgressIndicator(from now on - progressbar), that fills after a certain amount of time (each progressbar grows independently, one coroutine per each), and then self-destructs. And this is where things go off the rails.

How do you manage such a thing?

So now i started to think. Each bar should have it's own progress value and coroutine scope. But how in that case do you notify the column object (that contains all the progressbars) that the bar has ended it's job and must vanish?
You can put each BarClass in a mutablestatelist, sure, and build every bar by using @composable method inside that custom class of yours, but in that case - how could it remove itself from the list?
Do you just iterate through itself over and over, and in case any of those BarClasses tells you that the bar is done it's job you just remove it?
Or maybe there is another way to do it efficiently?